# MySQL update performance between bulk update and loop update

Tags: mysql

i have 2 codes that do the same thing 1 runs in 0.3 sec and 1 in 8 sec
i have a table with 10000 recorders, and i update all the record
also id column is indexed 
why there is such a time difference if they both do the same this ?

the first code( 0.3 sec):

```
UPDATE `trades` SET `profit_loss`= rand() WHERE id < 100000
```

the seconod code(8 sec):

```
    SET @a = 0 ;
    simple_loop: LOOP
       SET @a=@a+1;
       UPDATE trades SET profit_loss = rand() WHERE id = @a ;
       IF @a=10000 THEN
          LEAVE simple_loop;
       END IF;
```

END LOOP simple_loop;

Answer (score 0):

You're adding loop work in the second example without removing any of the work needing to be done in the first example.

Both examples require the line check, but the second example also requires 
1. variable updates.
2. loop exit criteria checks

Furthermore, the combination of `WHERE id = @a` and `IF @a=10000` is going to translate to a less efficient bytecode/parsetree structure than `WHERE id < 100000`. I am less sure of the details of this, but logically the more dynamic assignment is involved, the less efficient translation can be, even if it's just a matter of memory location update/rewrite.

Comment: hi.thanks for the answer.  i check your theory the loop it self without the update takes 0.2 sec so its not that. i suspect it happens because of the locking  but i don`t know  how to disable and enable lock Manley

Comment: I don't think locking and unlocking is the problem. from the MySQL documentation: "UPDATE ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters. " ( dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html ) This locking is happening as a result to the Update call, not the loop instantiation. However, I think I figured it out. It's not what I thought before. I will make a new answer. It is quite simple :)

Answer (score 0):

The extra time has to do with how many rows are being searched in each case. I know you say your id column is indexed, but the logic holds either way:

Lets use the following similar example

`UPDATE trades SET profit_loss= rand() WHERE id = 5`

When this is called, before modifying anything it is first checking as many lines as it needs to in order to find the line where that WHERE condition is met. If your search column is indexed, that search is more efficient, but still checks more lines than just the one that it ends up modifying. If it is not indexed it would use a cursor, start from the beginning, and go until it hits the condition meeting row. If your search column is unique, it will stop searching there. If not, it will continue until it has exhausted the table (or the matching index cluster(s) if you data is indexed).

Now if we call 
`UPDATE trades SET profit_loss= rand() WHERE id = 6` all of the previous search effort is wasted. Whether or not it is indexed it is going to be repeating a lot of the same searching.

Comparatively, if we call `UPDATE trades SET profit_loss= rand() WHERE id < 6`, the search is only going to happen once, but encompass the effect both of the previous updates. If it's not indexed the cursor will go over each table row once to check. If it's indexed then it may only search matching clusters

Either way, you can see that what you're doing in your first example is `check the table 1 times and modify (0..N) rows`. Your second example is `check the table N times and modify (0..1) rows each time`.

Also, I know that it isn't the main part of what you're asking, but if your only goal is to modify every record in the table, you don't need a `WHERE` clause at all. `UPDATE trades SET profit_loss= rand()` is legal syntax.

To verify this, run the following tests:

`UPDATE trades SET profit_loss = rand() WHERE id <= 10`

then try

```
UPDATE trades SET profit_loss = rand() WHERE id = 1
UPDATE trades SET profit_loss = rand() WHERE id = 2
UPDATE trades SET profit_loss = rand() WHERE id = 3
...
UPDATE trades SET profit_loss = rand() WHERE id = 10
```

When you compare times you should see a noticeable difference.

Comment: I've added a test plan. Please test and mark as answer and/or upvote if I am correct, as I am new and want to establish street cred :)